# Asynchronous Operation in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

Мне нужно выполнить background операцию, которая занимает много времени в моем WCF-сервисе. Сервис не должен быть заблокирован во время выполнения этой операции. Вызов операции происходит из контроллера.
Server Side:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetMessages(int sleep);
}

public class HelloService : IServiceContract
{
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetMessages(int sleep)
    {
        var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(sleep);
            return "Return from Server after: " + sleep;
        });
        return await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
public partial class HelloServiceClient : ClientBase<IServiceContract>,
                                          IServiceContract {
   public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetMessages(int sleep)
   {
       return Channel.GetMessages(sleep);
   }
```

Использование в контроллере:

```
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetResult(int sleep)
    {
       var client = DAACommunicationServiceHelper.CreateClient();
       SystemLogManager.Current.Write("Start GetResult: " + sleep);
       var result = await client.GetMessages(sleep);
       SystemLogManager.Current.Write("GetResult = " + result);
       SystemLogManager.Current.Write("End GetResult: " + sleep);
       return result;
    }
```

После этого я отправила 2 запроса:

```
POST https://localhost:44374/Services/Maintenance.asmx/GetResult HTTP/1.1
{"sleep":1000}
```

и сразу

```
POST https://localhost:44374/Services/Maintenance.asmx/GetResult HTTP/1.1
{"sleep":1}
```

Я ожидала что запрос "sleep":1 выполниться быстрее, но WCF-сервис был заблокирован пока не выполнился запрос "sleep":10000.

Вот что в логах:

```
2017-06-14 11:25:16.1684 INFO Start GetResult: 10000
2017-06-14 11:25:19.3156 INFO Start GetResult: 1
2017-06-14 11:25:26.1802 INFO GetResult = Return from Server after: 10000
2017-06-14 11:25:26.1802 INFO End GetResult: 10000
2017-06-14 11:25:26.1802 INFO GetResult = Return from Server after: 1
2017-06-14 11:25:26.1802 INFO End GetResult: 1
```

**UPD:**
Почему WCF-сервис был заблокирован пока не выполнился запрос "sleep":10000? Мне нужно чтобы WCF-сервис выполнял операцию асинхронно и запросы возвращались по мере выполнения. 
В логах я рассчитывала увидеть такое:

```
2017-06-14 11:25:16.1684 INFO Start GetResult: 10000
2017-06-14 11:25:19.3156 INFO Start GetResult: 1
2017-06-14 11:25:26.1802 INFO GetResult = Return from Server after: 1
2017-06-14 11:25:26.1802 INFO End GetResult: 1
2017-06-14 11:25:26.1802 INFO GetResult = Return from Server after: 10000
2017-06-14 11:25:26.1802 INFO End GetResult: 10000
```

Comment: Вообще, в коде явных ошибок нет, выглядит правильно. Попробовал создать консольное приложение с self-hosted сервисом и подключиться к нему из двух экземпляров Wcf Test Client (да, я понимаю, что он не отправляет асинхронные запросы) и у меня лог на сервере wcf именно такой, на который вы рассчитывали. Возможно, стоит собрать полностью идентичное окружение - дописать клиент, поместить его в mvc-проект и дёрнуть снаружи.

Comment: Спасибо! Проверила на чистом проекте и заметила что на реальном проекте для сервиса было указано  [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]. Проблема решилась добавлением ConcurrencyMode.Multiple

Comment: Не пишите ответ в комментарии, оформите ответом и примите (галка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверила на чистом проекте и заметила что на реальном проекте для сервиса было указано [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]. Проблема решилась добавлением ConcurrencyMode.Multiple